# Puppeteer taking up too much space. Can't push app to Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, puppeteer

I have a very small node app I am trying to push to Heroku, but puppeteer is taking up so much space that I am exceeding the 500MB slug size limit (532MB when compiled). What can I do to bring the slug size down? Everything else in node_modules is under 2MB.

Comment: do you use the official Puppeteer Heroku buildpack?

Answer (score 0):

Must Puppeteer install and run on Heroku? If not, remove it from `package.json`.  Or, consider moving Puppeteer from package.json's `dependencies` to `devDependencies`.

If you do need Puppeteer running remotely on a server in the cloud, consider using a pre-existing cloud service that runs Puppeteer scripts:

- Google Cloud Functions - [Serverless web performance monitoring using Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/serverless-web-performance-monitoring-using-cloud-functions?hl=en#collecting_page_performance_metrics)
- AWS CloudWatch - [Using synthetic monitoring](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Synthetics_Canaries.html)